# Can objects in a fluid sim be animated?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

What I am planning is to have water stay in the cup then when I rotate the cup to make water fall out.

Can blender do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the simulated fluid will be affected by animated obstacles.

Comment: Thank yout #TobiasE that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great, please accept this answer if that is the case. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work